# using SOCKS and still have pages blocked

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, socks5

On Ubutnu, Using firefox:  
i set it in firefox network setting(SOCKS5) when i check my ip (i.e whatsmyip.com) it is the socks server's ip, but when trying to access youtube.com it's blocked
why?!

in about:config i have set use_remote_socks_dns to true, no change, set DNS server of my router to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 , no change again, used wireshark, just got more confused...  
  
i know this has been asked before and it seems everyone has got their problem fixed except for me, can you please tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know about ubuntu but it's not relevant to my comment.  if one website works w.g. http://www.whatismyip.org/ (dot org is better than dot com by the way since it just gives the ip plain). Then the SOCKS is working. Perhaps you're using a public SOCKS proxy and youtube has it on a ban list?

Comment: it's a firefox bug! which i couldn't find a workaround except using this application: "proxychain", FF doesnt regard the option socks_remote_dns, i dont like using proxychains much, i want the firefox to work, the web site is blocked at DNS server, (it's obvious from FF behavior, and wireshark)

Comment: I haven't tried it but have you tried Proxifier? It may be like Proxychains. Proxychains is a proxifier(according to its description). But it looks like there's an app called Proxifier too so may be worth trying that. (not to be confused with a browsing anonymizing website called proxify!)

Comment: why not set firefox internally to use a proxy?  perhaps  an app like Proxychains is more for an app that doesn't have an internal setting to give it a proxy to use.

Comment: proxifier is just and only for windows, unfortunately! because it works amazingly, supporting every single protocol in the world and working with any server with any nasty configuration..., i love to set proxy settings internally as i said firefox doesn't regard the remote-DNS-through-socks option, all the requests are blocked at DNS server side, even if use ip address manually, there is elements in every page which don't, the bug report for FF is risen, but no fix yet

Comment: by the way, wine+proxifier=not working=waisted my money on it, if it worked it was worth the trouble of using wine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, seems it's a firefox bug and not fixed, in ubuntu at least, 
workaround: use "**proxychains**", which works like a charm, 
but! loosing the nice future of foxyproxy

Answer (score 1):

Open a new tab in Firefox and type in `about:config`. In the search bar, type `network.proxy.socks_remote_dns` and  set this entry to **true**.

In addition, you should go to Edit → Preferences → Advanced → Network → Settings to set the proxy correctly. Don't use Network proxy in the Network of System setting. That just gives you "The connection was reset".

Or you can use Google Chrome browser.